# How to show JavaScript function value inside input text value

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code to measure number of inputs in each text input and need to show it on input text but could figure it out!:

```html
<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Can Validate Input</h2>

  <p>Please input a number </p>

  <input id="numb1" value="">
  <input id="numb2" value="">
  <input id="numb3" value="">

  <input id="demo" type="text" value="I want to add the value of z from myFunction()">

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      const inputs = ['numb1', 'numb2', 'numb3'];
      const z = inputs.map(v => document.getElementById(v).value)
        .reduce((a, v) => a + (v && !isNaN(v)), 0);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Thanks for all

Comment: So, what's wrong with the code?

Comment: in `const z` you haven't included `" " / ' '` in `v`.

Comment: @Teemu I want to cal the `myFunction()` inside input text value.

Comment: "I have this code to measure number of inputs" what do you mean by "measure number of inputs"? This expression `v && !isNaN(v)` returns either empty string or boolean.

Comment: @M.Saeed use `onchange= "myFunction()"` or `onkeyup="myFunction"` if you want to run it as you type a value in the input, or use a button and use `onclick="myFunction"`

Comment: You want what? Do you mean you want to call the function when the value of an input changes? Notice, that input elements don't have innerHTML, they have value.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko the script is working as I need, which If I entered any number in input text will measure it as a one. but need to show the `z` value from JS function inside value of text input

Comment: is this the entire code? whats in `document.getElementById(v).value`?

Comment: use `document.getElementById("demo").value= z;` and add the `onchange` or `onkeyup` in the input. it should work

Comment: Working code: https://jsfiddle.net/pcb23uty/1/

Comment: @HishamBawa yes thank you..it works with me with your instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't look like the way but it seems like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>JavaScript Can Validate Input</h2>

<p>Please input a number </p>

<input id="numb1">
<input id="numb2">
<input id="numb3">

<input id="demo" type="text" value="I want to add the value of z from myFunction()">

<script>

    function myFunction() {
      let inputs = ['numb1', 'numb2', 'numb3'];
      let z=inputs.reduce((a, i) => {
        let v = document.getElementById(i).value;
        return a+(parseInt(v) || 0);
        },0);
      document.getElementById("demo").value=z;
    }

document.getElementById('numb1').addEventListener('input', myFunction);
document.getElementById('numb2').addEventListener('input', myFunction);
document.getElementById('numb3').addEventListener('input', myFunction);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can set event listener on Class and use ```getElementsByClassName``` too, which prettier and dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

The input element has no `innerHtml` capabilities. Replace that with value. 
Should be `document.getElementById("demo").value = z;`